# Receive error before click Ok on Location Dialog Bog

Tags: android, location

My code:

```
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
            builder.addLocationRequest(new LocationRequest().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY));
            builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
            mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

            mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(MainActivity.this);

            mSettingsClient
                    .checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                            //Success Perform Task Here
                            Log.d("MyApp", "OK!" + Double.toString(latitude));
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                            Log.e("MyApp","Failure ."+ Integer.toString(statusCode));
                            switch (statusCode) {
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                    try {
                                        ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                        rae.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {
                                        Log.e("MyApp","Unable to execute request.");
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                    Log.e("MyApp","Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Fix in Settings.");
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCanceled() {
                            Log.e("GPS","checkLocationSettings -> onCanceled");
                        }
                    });
```

So this code will pop up the Location enable prompt (like in Maps). Problem is right after the dialog box pop up, OnFailureListener is already called. Even before I click Ok or Cancel.

The error log:

> Failure .6

Any idea why?

---

**EDIT** To make clear my question:

Why is it that right after the dialog box pop up, OnFailureListener is already called. Even before I click Ok or Cancel. Why is this so? I was under the impression that onsuccess/onfailurelistener should only be called AFTER i click Ok or Cancel. If I am wrong, then how can I get the response AFTER i click Ok or Cancel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The location enable prompt is displayed due to your code within the OnFailureListener.

```
case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
    try {
        ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
        rae.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {
        Log.e("MyApp","Unable to execute request.");
    }
    break;
```

Status code `6` matches the `LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED` case which you are then handling by calling `startResolutionForResult`. You'll receive the result in your `MainActivity` `onActivityResult` function.

Basically what I'm saying is, what you're describing is expected behaviour.

Edit:

To clarify, it's *this* code that makes the dialog pop up

```
rae.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
```

Which occurs inside your OnFailureListener. The OnFailureListener is called when the device's settings do not allow for location, such as if the location setting is switched off. By calling `startResolutionForResult` you can *resolve* the error that just happened, which in this case would pop up a dialog box to enable location settings. You can then respond to the result of that dialog in your `MainActivity.onActivityResult`.

So the flow is

1. Check location settings
2. If OnSuccessListener is called, you can locate, great!
3. If OnFailureListener is called, the device currently cannot locate. Check the status code to see if the error is resolvable
4. If the error is not resolvable, you're out of luck
5. If the error is resolvable, attempt to resolve the error
6. Respond to the error resolution in `MainActivity.onActivityResult`

Comment: I edited my question to make clear my question.